# How to get value of EditText in listView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I want to get the value of editText in the first row of my ListView can anyone tell me how to do this. I'm trying this but it doesn't work.

```
      View v = (View) S_4th_SelectItem.lst_listOrder.getChildAt(0);
      myHolder.txt_Qty = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_QTY);
      String qty = myHolder.txt_Qty.getText().toString();
      myHolder.txt_Qty.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you receive an exception? An unexpected string? Please describe exactly your observation

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work correctly.

```
Database file:



     String strcol[] = new String[] { "Date1", "Time", "Title" };

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> retrieve() {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ar = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        Cursor c = db.query("LOGIN", strcol, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            String dat = c.getString(0);
            String tim = c.getString(1);
            // String due=c.getString(2);
            // String end=c.getString(3);
            // String cat=c.getString(4);
            // String not=c.getString(5);
            String titl = c.getString(2);
    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hmap.put("date", dat);
            hmap.put("time", tim);
            hmap.put("title", titl);
            ar.add(hmap);
            c.moveToNext();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Check ar size at ret", "" + ar.size());
    return ar;
}
```

In this file i create user define method where i put the values.

.javafile(get data in list view as)-:

```
public class List_activity extends Activity {
Login_database login_database;
ListView lv;
 Dialog listDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al;
Button btn1,btn2,edt_data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view1);
    edt_data=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edt_data);
    edt_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    try 
    {
        login_database=new Login_database(this);
        login_database.open();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        al=login_database.retrieve();
   ListAdapter ld=new SimpleAdapter(List_activity.this, al, R.layout.list_view, new String[]{"date","time","title"}, new    int[]{R.id.listDesignTxtDate,R.id.listDesignTxtTime,R.id.listDesignTxtTitle});
     ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(List_activity.this, new R.layout.list_view,R.id.listDesignTxt,al);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        lv.setAdapter(ld);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it works properly on my app where i enter the value in edittext and reterive it in listview